# What algorithm that was used on the sentiment analysis code in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, classification, sentiment-analysis

I have a question regarding on the sentiment analysis. I have a data contains on tweets(Cryptocurrency). I'm planning to do sentiment analysis to get the positive and negative result for each tweets.

I found good sentiment analysis code, but because i'm new to to this area. I don't know what  classification algorithm that was used on this. Here's the code:

```
# importing Libraries
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import chardet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
from matplotlib import rc
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
import re
import warnings

#Visualisation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.display import display
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

#nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk.sentiment.util import *
from nltk import tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')


matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

%matplotlib inline



#########Sentiment Analysis code########

tweets['text_lem'] = [''.join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', line)) for line in lists]).strip() for lists in tweets['text']]       
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,max_features=10000,min_df=10,stop_words='english',use_idf=True)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets['text_lem'].str.upper())
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
tweets['sentiment_compound_polarity']=tweets.text_lem.apply(lambda x:sid.polarity_scores(x)['compound'])
tweets['sentiment_neutral']=tweets.text_lem.apply(lambda x:sid.polarity_scores(x)['neu'])
tweets['sentiment_negative']=tweets.text_lem.apply(lambda x:sid.polarity_scores(x)['neg'])
tweets['sentiment_pos']=tweets.text_lem.apply(lambda x:sid.polarity_scores(x)['pos'])
tweets['sentiment_type']=''
tweets.loc[tweets.sentiment_compound_polarity>0,'sentiment_type']='POSITIVE'
tweets.loc[tweets.sentiment_compound_polarity==0,'sentiment_type']='NEUTRAL'
tweets.loc[tweets.sentiment_compound_polarity<0,'sentiment_type']='NEGATIVE'
```

Can anyone tell me more information about sentiment Analysis code?
What algorithm  that was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classifier in this code is a `SentimentIntensityAnalyser()`. The [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html) indicates that it could be a NaiveBayesClassifier.

If you access the original paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312176414_Sentiment_Analysis_in_Python_using_NLTK) they also mention the NaiveBayesClassifier.

However, from the [github project](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment), the authors indicate:

> The Python code for the rule-based sentiment analysis engine. Implements the grammatical and syntactical rules described in the paper, incorporating empirically derived quantifications for the impact of each rule on the perceived intensity of sentiment in sentence-level text.

Thus the algorithm in your code is a rule-based algorithm, not a machine learning algorithm. The code is [here](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vaderSentiment.py).

### Testing the library

Using the code from the paper:

```
hate_comments = ['I second that emotion! I can\'t understand how any decent human being could support them  considering their ongoing loathsome record. #ToriesOut2018 #NHSCrisis #CambridgeAnalytica',
             'Think we’d just share the ladder, Mikey pal. Nationalise all of the ladders and have a big old ladder party.',
             'The Tories, young and old, do not understand that where child poverty, homelessness and the destruction of the NHS are concerned, there is absolutely nothing to smile about. Well done Lara.',
             'I don\'t even like them!',
             'Boom! Get in......',
             'Me too',
             'That\'s fine, but do it with a smile.',
             'Yesss girl',
             'Me too!',
             'Ditto..',
             'one day she will be all grown up .. ah bless',
             'Who doesn\'t.',
             'I hate them too Lara'
              ]

for sentence in hate_comments:
    print(sentence)
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for k in ss:
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(k, ss[k]), end='')
        print()
```

[out]:

```
    I second that emotion! I can't understand how any decent human being could support them  considering their ongoing loathsome record. #ToriesOut2018 #NHSCrisis #CambridgeAnalytica
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 0.87, 
pos: 0.13, 
compound: 0.4574, 
Think we’d just share the ladder, Mikey pal. Nationalise all of the ladders and have a big old ladder party.
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 0.776, 
pos: 0.224, 
compound: 0.5994, 
The Tories, young and old, do not understand that where child poverty, homelessness and the destruction of the NHS are concerned, there is absolutely nothing to smile about. Well done Lara.
neg: 0.244, 
neu: 0.702, 
pos: 0.055, 
compound: -0.806, 
I don't even like them!
neg: 0.445, 
neu: 0.555, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: -0.3404, 
Boom! Get in......
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
Me too
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
That's fine, but do it with a smile.
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 0.518, 
pos: 0.482, 
compound: 0.5647, 
Yesss girl
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
Me too!
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
Ditto..
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
one day she will be all grown up .. ah bless
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 0.781, 
pos: 0.219, 
compound: 0.4215, 
Who doesn't.
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 1.0, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: 0.0, 
I hate them too Lara
neg: 0.552, 
neu: 0.448, 
pos: 0.0, 
compound: -0.5719,
```

You can observe that messages that escape the rules are not properly annotated such as `Yesss girl` or `Me too!` that should be positive.

A machine learning classifier is usually better for these cases if you can afford the cost of labeling a large amount of text to predict sentiments.